# Facebook graph API and Facebook groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two questions about Facebook GraphAPI and Facebook Group:

1. Is there some way to connect existing FB Group and new FB App?
2. I wanna add a new member of FB Group via FB Graph. I have code ([Graph API Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/members/#publish))

---

```
$postResult = $this->facebook->api("/GROUP_ID/members", "POST", 
      array (
        'member' => 'USER_ID',
      )
    );
```

but I still get error "**(#3) Unknown method**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/members/#publish) says:

> An app access token can invite any app users to a group created by that app.

So the request must be made with an [**app access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) and this same app app must have **created** that group.

You cannot send request to the friends if that group was not created using an app.

Comment: I see, but I had group before I created app and I need to connect them. Is it even possible?

Comment: In that case invite using Graph API is not possible!

Comment: And is there some way to connect this group and new app at least?

Comment: Connect in what sense?

Comment: I have a FB group. Now I've created a FB App (after the group). And I wanna invite/add next users to the group via FB Graph API.

Comment: That's what I've said, that its not possible! The quote from the documentation is quite straight-firward

Comment: I have one more problem - now I have app and through it created group, so I can invite/add new members of this group. It works perfect 2 days ago, but now I get error "(#3) Application must be whitelisted or users must be testers." and I can't add new member again.

I can't find anywhere what's a "whitelist" and how to add my App on it.